# How to I make this lua script repeat, please?

Tags: lua

I have been reading and watching tutorials on lua scripts trying to get it right, but I obviously have no idea how to do so. My question is how would I add a repeat to this script, please?

```lua
sell_all = {    101701, 101702, 101703, 101705, 101721, 101722, 101723, 101724, 102701, 102702, 102703, 102705, 102721, 102722, 102723, 102724, 103701, 103702, 103703, 103705, 103721, 103722, 103723, 103724, 
104701, 104702, 104703, 104705, 104721, 104722, 104723, 104724, 105701, 105702, 105703, 105705, 105721, 105722, 105723, 105724, 106701, 106702, 106703, 106705, 106721, 106722, 106723, 106724, 107701, 107702, 
107703, 107705, 107721, 107722, 107723, 107724, 108701, 108702, 108703, 108705, 108721, 108722, 108723, 108724, 109701, 109702, 109703, 109705, 109721, 109722, 109723, 109724, 110701, 110702, 110703, 110705, 
110721, 110722, 110723, 110724, 111701, 111702, 111703, 111706, 111721, 111722, 111723, 111724, 111725, 112701, 112702, 112703, 112705, 112721, 112722, 112723, 112724, 261701, 262701, 263701, 264701, 271701, 
271702, 271703, 271704, 271721, 271722, 271723, 272701, 272702, 272703, 272704, 272721, 272722, 272723, 273701, 273702, 273703, 273704, 273721, 273722, 273723, 274701, 274702, 274703, 274704, 274721, 274722, 
274723, 301702, 301703, 301704, 301705, 301706, 301707, 301708, 301709, 301710, 302701, 302705, 302709, 302713, 302717, 302721, 302725, 302729, 302733, 302737, 302741, 302745, 302749, 302750, 302751, 302752, 
303701, 303702, 303703, 303704, 303705, 303706, 303707, 303708, 303721, 303722, 303723, 303724, 304701, 304702, 304703, 304704, 304721, 304722, 304723, 304724, 305701, 305702, 305703, 305704, 305705, 305706, 
305707, 305708, 305709, 305710, 305711, 305712, 305713, 305714, 305715, 305716, 305717, 305718, 305721, 305722, 305723, 305724, 305725, 305726, 305727, 305728, 305729, 305730, 305731, 305732, 305733, 305734, 
305735, 305736, 305737, 305738, 305740, 305741, 305742, 305743, 305744, 305745, 306701, 313701, 313702, 313703, 313704, 313705, 313706, 313707, 313708, 313721, 313722, 313723, 313724, 313725, 313726, 313727, 
313728, 314701, 314702, 314703, 314704, 314705, 314706, 314707, 314708, 314709, 314710, 314711, 314712, 314721, 314722, 314723, 314724, 314725, 314726, 314727, 314728, 322701, 322702, 322703, 322704, 323701, 
323702, 323703, 323704, 324701, 324702, 324703, 324704, 417100, 417101, 417102, 417201, 427001, 427002, 427003, 427004, 427301, 437001, 437002, 437003, 437004, 437005, 437006, 437007, 437201, 437202, 690007, 
690107, 690207, 700112, 700156, 700157, 700212, 700256, 700257, 700312, 700507, 700607, 700657, 700707, 700757, 303101, 
250310105, 201310506, 203311110, 302320205, 220310103, 220310109, 220310107, 220310108, 303310205, 31310210,  301310613, 106310104, 210310102, 111310107, 220310104, 301310512, 301320711, 301320206, 230320105, 110320104,
301310708, 301310211, 302310307, 301310606, 112310111, 202310203, 240310106, 302310403, 104310110, 302310201, 107310108, 104310105, 301310108, 110310104, 110310103, 230410106, 112410104, 111310102, 210410103, 301310305,
201410510, 302310410, 301310507, 301410103, 302410108, 302410202, 301310208, 203410705, 203411111, 302310107, 301410209, 302410105, 210410102, 301410310, 301210109, 230310109, 301310210, 301410406, 301410303, 301310411,
202420604, 108310103, 302410405, 302410411, 301410213, 301410108, 220420109, 210410201, 102410103, 301410506, 103410105, 302410303, 111410103, 108410101, 302410408, 204411208, 301410204, 302410205, 101410107, 302410106,
301420203, 301410112, 106410110, 302510404, 230410104, 301410307, 302410107, 301510111, 302410208, 301410305, 108410110, 302410102, 301410309, 302410311, 202411006, 303510109, 105410111, 201410110, 301510311, 201410505,
108410104, 301410113, 112410102, 201410503, 210410108, 204510105, 202510101, 302420105, 230420104, 240420106, 104410110, 301410104, 301510211, 101510101, 301410312, 302510204, 250410108, 240410101, 302510105, 204410802,
113410110, 301410211, 112410105, 107420108, 230410109, 301410407, 302410211, 240510111, 103410104, 250510108, 230410111, 230410103, 301510413, 101410105, 301410106, 201410102, 302410302, 301410404, 202411004, 230410110,
210410107, 302410201, 301410710, 107510101, 250410107, 105410104, 220410109, 103510110, 220510110, 113420104, 302410304, 301510313, 210410111, 210410210, 301410711, 107410101, 204410405, 203410307, 113410111, 301410608,
302510101, 204411202, 111510110, 301510603, 107410106, 201410107, 201510110, 201410911, 301410705, 303410209, 105410103, 302510303, 201510107, 103410103, 301520309, 240410106, 302410305, 104410101, 201410506, 203510110,
240410107, 301510209, 203410303, 203510109, 302410310, 301510308, 301410203, 302410409, 302510109, 250510111, 106410109, 204421209, 113420101, 201420111, 202421009, 106410105, 230410108, 302510307, 240510105, 301410707,
301410311, 202410201, 301510106, 202510104, 103410106, 250410103, 103510101, 204410807, 201410909, 110510101, 111510106, 220410107, 220410104, 201420104, 103410108, 302510405, 302510402, 250410105, 301410603, 102510110,
301510305, 101410110, 301510205, 301410709, 301510110, 302410109, 301510504, 202510106, 301410511, 112410103, 201510103, 301510409, 302410306, 201410905, 301410411, 250510106, 220510106, 301410503, 210410211, 301410313,
302510107, 107410107, 112410101, 210410206, 302410206, 110410102, 301510206, 301410212, 220410103, 230410107, 108510109, 301510703, 201410508, 201410104, 102510111, 202410610, 301410304, 301410107, 302410103, 302510304,
202410211, 203510102, 250510104, 302410301, 301410109, 104410107, 302410404, 113510108, 104510110, 301510507, 301410205, 250410111, 204510110, 303510203, 202410205, 201410903, 301410405, 303510111, 203411109, 210410204,
301410708, 301510307, 102410105, 210410202, 104410102, 302410101, 302510102, 240510110, 105410107, 301410206, 204510102, 113410104, 101420104, 106510108, 201510104, 210410109, 107510106, 301510612, 301510103, 202410608,
105710106, 301710507, 302710104, 301710104, 204411201, 301410704, 210410104, 302410407, 220410102, 203410704, 201410511, 301410605, 105410109, 104410105, 108410102, 108410107, 203510108, 204410811, 203410306, 301410208,
240410102, 301510711, 204410410, 220410105, 301410507, 240410103, 203510101, 201410910, 301410513, 107410105, 203411102, 302410110, 230410101, 240410110, 302410308, 301410306, 210410106, 102410111, 220410101, 230510101,
301410509, 302410307, 301410403, 104410106, 301410610, 240410104, 103410111, 220410110, 101410103, 302410406, 210410209, 203411108, 201410103, 240410111, 202410206, 203510104, 106410107, 203410710, 202411007, 301410308,
112410110, 302510407, 250410102, 302410401, 201410507, 302410203, 103410110, 210411201, 204410809, 210510102, 301410105, 101410106, 110510103, 202410210, 204410805, 240410109, 303510106, 203410301, 301410712, 301510513,
302410209, 203411105, 201410111, 110410105, 101410104, 202411001, 301510412, 110410104, 108410105, 301410505, 113410107, 203410701, 202411003, 102410109, 302510309, 203411106, 210410105, 110410103, 113410101, 301410512,
108510111, 240420111, 202410203, 201410502, 302420108, 202411005, 203410702, 203411103, 220510104, 203410707, 202411009, 102410106, 103410102, 301410110, 230410105, 220410106, 111410102, 201410108, 105410101, 113410108,
230410102, 302410402, 301510710, 107410104, 107410102, 203411104, 204410803, 302410309, 102410107, 111410105, 303410111, 250410110, 113510109, 104420108, 113410103, 101410109, 106420108, 204520110, 302410410, 302510205,
113410102, 201420510, 204410402, 202410204, 101410102, 202410208, 108410108, 250410101, 302510211, 108410103, 204410411, 301410703, 302410403, 301510312, 301410111, 204421204, 204411206, 204410810, 204410409, 301510611,
201410901, 301410607, 108510103, 204510106, 202410202, 210420106, 111410109, 106410103, 202410607, 301510212, 110410109, 111410104, 301410207, 201510102, 202410606, 210410208, 302510401, 201510108, 112410109, 201510106,
201410906, 301710405, 230710311, 302710105, 111710103, 301720503, 201710110, 302710401, 301710511, 111710106, 301710410, 301710303, 112710110, 201720111, 302710203, 106710104, 203710302, 202710202, 301710105, 301710304,
111720102, 202710210, 301710204, 111710108, 230710308, 104710111, 301710307, 202710205, 301710311, 202710206, 301710113, 107710102, 301710203, 250710101, 301710205, 220710103, 108720108, 202710211, 201710106, 101710101,
103710108, 204710404, 302710305, 250710104, 105710105, 302710403, 203710306, 301710603, 230710405, 301710406, 250710102, 203710301, 302710204, 210710110, 301710103, 301710208, 210710111, 203710304, 301710610, 204710406,
302710306, 302710307, 302710303, 105710107, 201710108, 301710306, 202710201, 250710105, 111710105, 302710202, 220710108, 113710105, 210710411, 302710208, 301710106, 301710109, 301710209, 220710109, 250710107, 202710204,
106710103, 201710109, 302710110, 301710313, 250710106, 302710209, 301710712, 250710110, 220710102, 220710110, 303710205, 112710107, 230710105, 302710311, 302710301, 203710310, 302710206, 102710102, 203710309, 230710111,
105710102, 101710108, 301710605, 204710402, 210710108, 301710509, 301710412, 301710309, 230710411, 301710411, 204710409, 107710110, 113710111, 111710102, 301710305, 301710508, 302710103, 230710207, 303710211, 104710108,
210710403, 302710304, 302710201, 230710210, 301710703, 101710102, 302710409, 303720308, 301710611, 201710101, 301710409, 301720508, 250710108, 240710110, 113710104, 240710206, 220710101, 112710106, 103710102, 230710310,
301710213, 301710706, 110710101, 201710105, 301710207, 240710308, 302710407, 108710103, 303710302, 105710103, 101710105, 106710106, 230710309, 302710302, 302710106, 302710108, 203710307, 108710105, 301720613, 204710410,
101710109, 302710111, 102710105, 301710513, 204710401, 301710710, 105710101, 210710107, 230710211, 201710111, 301710503, 240710403, 302710210, 303710101, 230710404, 303710109, 301710607, 110710109, 201710103, 302710309,
301720510, 301710510, 105710109, 301710704, 302710411, 107520107, 302520104, 210520204, 201520101, 301520304, 230710302, 301710504, 240710202, 301710206, 202710209, 302710207, 230710402, 302710107, 240710208, 107530108,     
203520102, 204520102, 101520101, 301520307, 220520108, 301520603, 301520308, 230520101, 220520106, 108420104, 113430109, 108520204, 301520204, 105520108, 301520312, 112520104, 202520106, 240420105, 112420102, 204520108,
301520510, 301520412, 202420203, 103520104, 201520105, 301520712, 302420208, 220520104, 107420106, 230420108, 101420105, 301520411, 105520106, 240530108, 201420904, 301420413, 104420107, 110520207, 112530109, 302520205,
301420104, 301420604, 250520111, 202520107, 230420111, 107420111, 106420101, 113420103, 210420103, 103420106, 108420103, 113420106, 301420205, 250420104, 230420105, 210420209, 107420107, 107520103, 210520104, 113520103,
106420106, 301420109, 202420603, 240420102, 230420109, 301420409, 250420110, 301420607, 301520310, 302420109, 202420211, 202420607, 302520305, 107420110, 301420411, 204420411, 302420207, 110420109, 230430105, 301420603,
302430205, 302430211, 302420302, 204421207, 202420206, 108510105, 111420105, 302420409, 230510103, 112510111, 230520110, 301520711, 220510108, 110510110, 240510104, 240510102, 302510104, 301510404, 301510105, 301510104,
301510203, 220510109, 202510109, 301510410, 301510310, 204510108, 103510103, 112510101, 105410108, 230510104, 101410111, 203510107, 302510203, 210510110, 301510213, 210410205, 201510105, 105410105, 110510102, 303410201,
301510108, 220420101, 203410711, 250410104, 303510201, 108510101, 112510110, 204411205, 201410907, 302510306, 250510109, 201410106, 201510109, 301410504, 302510408, 301510505, 240510109, 110510108, 301510303, 302510411,
203420311, 110420103, 301420712, 220510111, 302510207, 302410207, 101510107, 220410111, 303510301, 113410106, 203410310, 204510109, 250410109, 204410806, 301410510, 105410106, 303410203, 301410713, 302410104, 210410110,
201410908, 204411210, 106410111, 102410104, 113410109, 111410106, 110410101, 204411207, 105410102, 301410606, 301410604, 301410412, 101410108, 108410109, 107410110, 302410210, 302410204, 202410209, 106410104, 107410111,
204410407, 112410111, 301410611, 301310609, 202310605, 202310209, 201310105, 202310604, 202310210, 103310102, 220310102, 302310202, 302310407, 203310304, 302310310, 110410110, 301310603, 203310709, 203310701, 301310113,
201310502, 250310111, 105310109, 301310104, 301310610, 301310712, 302320402, 202310205, 201320102, 204321205, 101320101, 103320101, 301320107, 301320413, 301320506, 220310106, 250310103, 104310111, 230310106, 301310311,
202310204, 202310206, 202311011, 104310102, 204310402, 301310112, 204311203, 203310702, 210310111, 240320111, 302310103, 230310103, 203311104, 303320105, 240310107, 302310305, 301310604, 202311006, 302310104, 301310605,
301310503, 302310406, 203320304, 301320603, 303320203, 302310102, 301310509, 203210306, 110310106, 301310506, 301210603, 302210401, 240210101, 301210313, 107210101, 204210807, 220210101, 240210105, 301210708, 230210111,
240210103, 201210502, 301210312, 301210113, 102210102, 202210607, 302210211, 112210106, 302210208, 301210604, 101210103, 302210304, 601100207, 301210311, 203210307, 204210407, 210210207, 210210103, 201210103, 204210804,
202210604, 203211104, 201210102, 202210610, 302210103, 210210211, 112210103, 301210210, 301210306, 301210509, 202210211, 101210105, 302210309, 102210104, 103210109, 301210205, 230210103, 250210103, 301210303, 204210805,
230210110, 250210107, 112210109, 240210102, 104210102, 101210110, 301210704, 301210310, 301210305, 301210607, 301210207, 302210408, 301210407, 301210212, 302210306, 301210105, 301210106, 302210411, 204210803, 105210111,
108210105, 303220205, 303210209, 108210110, 302210407, 301210404, 101220111, 302210405, 113210103, 250210104, 201210904, 301210208, 240210109, 105220110, 113210101, 210210104, 302220202, 230210102, 301210112, 110220104,
111220105, 204220803, 220220107, 220220110, 302220308, 302220103, 202220607, 204210808, 106210107, 107210107, 105220107, 210210203, 203210302, 302210206, 301210706, 204210811, 112210101, 601100208, 240210110, 102210111,
302210209, 302210210, 301210406, 302210310, 204210401, 107210108, 112210107, 301210611, 220210111, 220210103, 301210705, 301210408, 220210106, 107210102, 210210109, 210210206, 105210107, 203210701, 301210104, 204210810,
104210110, 302210302, 201210510, 301210103, 210210210, 103210101, 106210101, 301220208, 301210605, 250210101, 220210107, 303210109, 210210106, 250210108, 301210413, 106210106, 201210908, 202211001, 202211008, 302210311,
201210507, 202210210, 201210508, 302210402, 230220106, 301220412, 204210408, 302210301, 203210709, 210210204, 110210111, 202210603, 301210110, 202720201, 102710101, 301720609, 240710101, 204710403, 230710102, 250710109,
240710108, 250710103, 303710307, 110710102, 303710106, 303710303, 302710310, 103710106, 302710410, 240710105, 301710312, 103710110, 113710109, 210710402, 203710308, 111710104, 103710109, 301710310, 240710408, 302710308,
240710104, 302710402, 220710107, 302710405, 220720101, 301710705, 203710305, 107710105, 110710103, 230710406, 220710111, 302710211, 104720106, 106710110, 108710108, 301710211, 240710410, 230710401, 110710111, 301710407,
108710106, 112710102, 110710106, 302710404, 240710309, 302710101, 112710103, 111710109, 103710104, 230710201, 106710111, 301710210, 101710111, 201710104, 107710106, 203720304, 240710107, 210710407, 302720204, 301710707,
240710305, 301710606, 111710110, 230710106, 240710402, 301710111, 302720402, 204710411, 202720210, 301720404, 102720110, 302720103, 301720109, 108720406, 108720102, 301730311, 301720708, 105730409, 302720311, 302720210,
201720107, 302720101, 204730410, 106730404, 302730201, 301720407, 302720404, 301720206, 107720408, 301720411, 240720302, 204720401, 230720102, 105730404, 301720405, 204720405, 101720110, 301720705, 230720304, 210720409,
302720211, 301720203, 301720608, 302720111, 302720302, 204720402, 303720209, 110720104, 202730208, 240720303, 202720205, 301730613, 240720403, 240720211, 210720402, 110720110, 301720408, 240720309, 113720110, 107720107,
301720409, 301720311, 203720305, 204720404, 203720302, 111720107, 103720111, 302720303, 301720312, 301720710, 301720307, 112720103, 250720103, 210730105, 105720111, 301730511, 302730407, 302730109, 
                    
602001, 602002, 602003, 602004, 602005, 602006, 602007, 602008, 602101, 602102, 602106, 602201, 602202, 602203, 602204, 602205, 602206, 602207, 602208, 602301, 602302, 602303, 602304, 602305, 
602306, 602401, 602402, 602403, 602501, 602502, 602503, 602504, 602505, 602105, 602103, 602104, 602506, 900011, 807003, 807603, 808203, 806703, 805203, 809103, 807303, 808503, 809403, 805803, 
806103, 806403, 809703, 807903, 805503, 810003, 808803, 810004, 805204, 806404, 810301, 810302, 810303, 810304, 810305, 810306, 810307, 810308, 810309, 810310, 810311, 810312, 810313, 810314, 
810201, 810202, 810203, 810204, 810205, 810206, 810207, 810208, 810209, 810210, 810211, 810212, 810213, 810214, 900000, 806104, 807604, 806704, 809704, 807304, 809404, 808204, 809104, 808804, 
808504, 807004, 805504, 805804, 807904, 950080, 523017, 523203, 504003, 503156, 503186, 503603, 523006, 523007, 503033, 502001, 503412, 503027, 523428, 503411, 506010, 503013, 503601, 503016,
503435, 503602, 502601, 504412, 524402, 503035, 504614, 502630, 502044, 502031, 503203, 502312, 503402, 502078, 502620, 504012, 503607, 523425, 523605, 502313, 503428, 523427, 502322, 524406,
503185, 503188, 524802, 503211, 503222, 502067, 503754, 523005, 524401, 523015, 524801, 502041, 523012, 502303, 503212, 522008, 502012, 503014, 502070, 502021, 522002, 503017, 502676, 522006,
502623, 523426, 503224, 502052, 523436, 523432, 523201, 503002, 502328, 523421, 503472, 503424, 503005, 524405, 504207, 503811, 502326, 524204, 502503, 502681, 523414, 502645, 502621, 523009,
502022, 522009, 502063, 503025, 523409, 503751, 503187, 502638, 523416, 503427, 502071, 502074, 523444, 504202, 502679, 502337, 503814, 502501, 523402, 503614, 550401, 502622, 502019, 523001,
523013, 523443, 502334, 503103, 503810, 502673, 524403, 523004, 522301, 503024, 523431, 522005, 522304, 503181, 523802, 504801, 503613, 523433, 502333, 522007, 502331, 550301, 523408, 503492,
502678, 523401, 523206, 503430, 503201, 523016, 502051, 502020, 523435, 503752, 502061, 522305, 502013, 502611, 502033, 503037, 503622, 503012, 523422, 523441, 502053, 502664, 503023, 502639,
523417, 502014, 503423, 502671, 502624, 523430, 502637, 502034, 502304, 502661, 502060, 523407, 503621, 503040, 503753, 503001, 503030, 503616, 503209, 523601, 503461, 503401, 502046, 522307,
503454, 502668, 502617, 523002, 502655, 524201, 522501, 503151, 502615, 502045, 523202, 504001, 523423, 503750, 503210, 502656, 523445, 503021, 502649, 523405, 502626, 523801, 502011, 522012,
523014, 550101, 524404, 502672, 502058, 502032, 502662, 502056, 550201, 522011, 523415, 503608, 301731, 301732, 809807, 809207, 806505, 806805, 805605, 807405, 808305, 808605, 808005, 808905, 
809805, 809205, 810105, 807705, 805905, 806205, 807105, 806105, 805505, 809705, 806705, 808205, 808004, 809804, 809204, 809504, 810104, 808904, 806504, 807104, 805304, 805904, 807704, 808304,
808505, 807605, 809105, 807005, 809405, 808805, 806405, 807305, 805205, 807905, 806402, 807302, 808802, 809102, 807002, 805202, 806702, 805802, 809402, 808502, 809702, 808202, 806102, 808201,
806101, 805801, 810001, 807001, 809401, 809101, 809701, 805201, 808801, 806701, 807301, 806401, 808501, 807901, 550102, 523603, 502043, 524203, 523604, 502641, 523412, 523602, 503202, 690436,
502602, 503022, 523406, 504612, 502635, 502311, 522303, 504413, 524803, 522001, 805501, 807601, 808607, 809507, 810107, 808307, 307021, 808907                                                                                                                                                                                              }
```

```lua
function sell_all_junk()
    local handle = 0
    local vigor_list_count = table.getn( sell_all )

    for i=1, vigor_list_count do
        handle = get_item_handle_list( sell_all[i] )  
        if handle ~= 0 then
            for y=1, table.getn( handle ) do
                if is_erasable_item( handle[y] ) == 1 then
                    price = get_item_price(handle[y]) / 4
                    insert_gold( price )
                    delete_item(handle[y], 1)
                    
                    repeat
                        handle[y] = handle[y] - 1
                    until handle[y] == 0
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This script works perfect without the repeat however it only sells one item at a time with each click, so I wanted it to sell say 100ish being that a lot of items stack up to 999.

**EDIT**

So I changed the repeat to:

```
repeat
    handle[y] = handle[y] - 1
until handle[y] == 0
```

and it worked!! However, it seems to only sell one at a time still :(

**EDIT 2.0**

I apologize for not putting the entire code up so that everyone could get a full understanding of what I am trying to accomplish here. I am trying to make one button on a merchant that I can click on in order to sell everything in my bag at once instead of having to put each item in the slot one at a time. I put the entire code up now to give a full understanding :)

Also, if you'll notice how I have a "blank" line in between the item ID's is because I have to manually put them in one by one :( and the bottom lines are the items that stack, the top ones do not. Should I separate the codes in order to sell the ones that do not stack vs the ones that do? Is there any way to put say 1...999999999 and it'll sell everything in between those numbers?

Thank everyone for taking their time to help a pour soul! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what a `handle` is and what `delete_item` or any other methods do, I can not provide a solution.

Therefore I can just point out whats definitely wrong:

```lua
repeat
    handle[y] = handle[y] - 1
until handle[y] == 0
```

basically is the same as

```lua
handle[y] = 0
```

If it doesn't set your item count to 0, `handle[y]` is not the amount.

This means I lack the information on how many items are available, which is required for what you have in mind.

Comment: I apologize as I didn't realize that the table was needed (I have a TON of item IDs in it) because I didn't want to spam the page so-to-speak, however I will list it all :) I thought that I posted the script works great **without** the repeat in it. I did change it and it works, however it only deletes one item at a time (I edited the post). Let me get it together and I will post it all out so everyone gets the full script and understanding of what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Just a few examples are enough :)

Comment: Please also include `delete_item`

Comment: ok I need to ask a little bit more: what is `get_item_handle_list`? It receives an item id and returns a list of handles. But what is a handle?

Comment: I edited the entire post to give everyone a more understanding of what is happening and what I am trying to accomplish. I didn't realize the entire script was needed and that was my fault :( -- If you could kindly reread the post up above it should be a little better on understanding what I was trying to ask. Again, I apologize for that. **EDIT** Oh and I don't fully understand when you say "You need to make sure you pay 99 times, Also make sure to not sell more items than this slot contains". Is that because I have: y=1? Should I just separate the items that stack and the ones that don't?

Comment: I still need to understand what the handle is :) It all depends on that little detail. What does a handle represent? I'll then update my answer to address your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, It gets the item id # and checks my bag to see if it's in the list and if so, then it will sell the item to the vendor and then return the gold to me (as well as list it in the chat). So it represents the number of items I have.

Comment: `So it represents the number of items I have.` And that's where I think the error is. The handle may not represent the amount. It does not fit with `delete_item` (I mean, what should this method do with an amount and a second integer?). That's why I try to get the code of `delete_item` so I can look for myself what a handle does.

Comment: Ok, I don't think that you understand me correctly or perhaps I am not very good at explaining it. The script works flawlessly, no errors what so ever at all. If I take out the "repeat" section it works perfectly. I was just adding that in there to show that I made a mistake and it wasn't working correctly with the "repeat" "until" only. I think the problem is that I have both the items that stack and do not stack together. It's probably much easier to write two scripts - one with items that do not stack (this one that already works) and one with items that do stack (I don't have yet).

Comment: Yes, your repeat does not work because you subtract handles. I can not provide an answer without knowing anything about your game. Why is it relevant whether items stack or now? You don't try to stack anyways? I update my answer based on what I have until I receive more information.

Comment: Oh ok. My game is called "Rappelz" (not sure if this helps you out or not) but in the game you have to manually put one item at a time into the vendor in order to sell. I completely misunderstood (didn't read between the lines rather) that you meant the repeat part. Some items in the game stacks (scrolls, stones, potions, etc) but some doesn't (armor, weapons, jewelry) so being that I have both the item ID's inside the table, I was just thinking (and I am guessing that I am wrong by your answer) that it would be much easier to separate them with two different scripts.

Comment: Maybe then the delete_item would work?

Comment: I don't know, I still have no information about the implementation of the game. Is there a source code repository available by any chance?

Comment: What "exactly" are you needing to know? Yes, you can easily google Rappelz private server and find a link to the source.

Comment: code. I just need the code behind delete_item. I have absolutely no information right now. No docu, no source code, no comments, no descriptions or anything. I see an array, which might be full of integers. No idea what those represent. You say it's the amount, but the code you sent implies it's not. If I finally get to know what the item's amount is I can provide an answer.

Comment: How are you saying that you have no comments, no descriptions or anything whenever I told you exactly what this script does? It doesn't actually "DELETE" items, it gives them to the vendor that you're selling to. Everytime I give you what you ask for then you come back with something else, over and over again. If you can't or don't know how to help, it's ok. But, the script works with the game, it doesn't have errors, it just sells one item from my inventory at a time and I wanted to sell the entire stack at once is all. I'm not sure what all you're wanting / requiring but no one else did.